# Converting swedish string to currency not converting properly

Tags: vb.net, cultureinfo

I am trying to convert "-10,00" from a string into a currency using the Swedish culture. Here is my code:

```
ByVal ci As System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE")
Convert.ToDecimal("-10,00").ToString("C", ci)
```

The output from the above code is: -1.000,00 kr, which is wrong. It should be -10,00 kr. Is there anything wrong with my approach?

**Solution:**

The solution is to pass the cultureInfo into the ToDecimal function as a second parameter.

```
ByVal ci As System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE")
Convert.ToDecimal("-10,00", ci).ToString("C", ci)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `Convert.ToDecimal`.

Comment: The values are dynamic and are coming from an ajax call. I am using the jquery.global (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-global) to convert the entered values into the format based on the country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `C` format specifier includes two decimal places.
To get rid of them, use `C0`.

Comment: I tried it and it returns -1.000 kr. Shouldn't it be -10.00kr ?

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal` isn't returning what you think it is.  Use a decimal literal.

Comment: I just tried Convert.ToDecimal("-10,00") and it returned -1000D.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you want it to be.

Comment: "-10,00" should return -10.00kr not -1.000,00 kr. I can actually pass the cultureinfo into the Convert.ToDecimal(.., ci), which converts the value properly and returns -10.00 kr. However when I try to convert now: 12.345,00, then I get an "input string not valid" exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Then your format isn't matching the CultureInfo.  You may want to create your own `NumberFormatInfo` with your format.

Comment: Actually I was able to get it working using this: 
Dim newValue1 As Decimal, Decimal.TryParse("12.345,00", NumberStyles.Currency, ci, newValue1)

Comment: Since you helped me to resolve this, I am marking your response as an answer. Thanks